# Formal alternative for "suck"

Tags: word-choice, formality, synonyms

What is a more decent/formal alternative for the word *suck*? I want to use it in the context of being bad at something.

To be precise, I want to translate "To suck less at a job every day" to formal English.

Comment: If your purpose is to use this for a CV, you should cast things in a positive, not negative, light. Even a negative construction phrased in acceptable formal English — say, "to be less awful at a job every day" — would be a red flag to recruiters. @AndrewLeach got it right when he told you to turn it around with a positive verb like *improve*. I suggest you try to focus on the bigger picture here.

Comment: The formal synonym for *suck* is *fellate*, albeit perhaps not in quite the sense you mean here. :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think you just used it. Any alternative is going to depend on exactly where you are using the phrase. A CV will need a different expression from chatting to your mother.

> I'm bad at ...
> I'm not all that good at ...
> I find it difficult to ...
> I can't ... for toffee.
>
> If I tried to arrange flowers it would end up looking like a hedge.

To *suck less* is to *improve*:

> Every day, I want to improve at ...
> I'd like to get better at ...
> I'm working at becoming more proficient in ...

Comment: to be precise I want to translate "To suck less at a job everyday" to a formal English, yes for a CV like document.

Answer (score 3):

You should be more careful because what you're writing is a CV and not just any story.

Basically, what you would like to say is that you suck **but** you are a "fast-learner."

Like you said, "I suck less at a job every day."

Now, the problem is how to word it because the expression "fast-learner" or "quick-learner" is actually a kind of cliche in CV writing.

You could say:

> "Positive attitude with ability to adapt to new challenges."

Or,

> "[Enthusiastic, knowledge-hungry learner, eager to meet challenges and
>   quickly assimilate new concepts.](http://www.ehow.com/info_8237903_resume-tips-learning-quickly.html)"

Or,

> "[Succeeded in only **_ months to educate myself in _** areas.](http://www.vetmed.wsu.edu/academic/counseling/resume.aspx)"

The last one is actually an example of how you can "*show*" and not "*tell*" that you are indeed a fast-learner.