# Taking L's on the daily

Tags: word-choice

> I am disappointed to inform y'all that your boi Noah took a phat L.

[Formal alternative for "suck"](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/74576/formal-alternative-for-suck?rq=1)

In using this example, I am wondering what a good alternative might be for "taking phat L's on the daily."

I was considering "an instance in which I failed to meet expectations," but am not sure it fits.

Comment: To fulfill the "on the daily" part of your informal phrase, I might say "consistently failing to meet expectations" or "regularly missing the mark."

Comment: How about "a constant disappointment"?

Comment: Where does this sentence come from?  It is hard to know what it means without context.

Comment: Doesn't it mean taking big losses every day?

Comment: A phat L is a loss?  I thought "on the daily" could refer to the Daily Show, and Noah to Trevor Noah; and that the original might have been "I am disappoint" rather than I am disappointed.

Comment: What does the linked question have to do with this question?